# sam build botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, deep-learning, sam

I am trying to deploy my machine learning model with sam for couple of days and I am getting this error:
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
I am also make sure that my aws config is fine
the "aws s3 ls" command works fine with me any help will be useful thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've read through this issue which seems to have been deployed in v1.53: [SAM Accelerate issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3264)

Reading that seemed to imply that it might be worth trying

```
sam deploy --guided --profile mark
```

`--profile mark` is the new part and `mark` is just the name of the profile.

I'm using v1.53 but still have to pass in the profile to avoid the problem you're having and I was having, so they may not have fixed the issue as well as intended, but at least the `--profile` seems to solve it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, this error can be caused by a misalignment between a docker root installation and user-level AWS credentials.

Amazon documentation recommends adding credentials using the `aws configure` command without `sudo`. However, when you install docker on Linux, it requires a root-level installation. This ultimately results in the user being forced to use `sudo` for the SAM CLI `build` and `deploy` commands, which leads to the error.

There are two different solutions that will fix the issue:

- [Allow non-root users to manage docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/). If you use this method, you will not need to use `sudo` for your SAM CLI commands. This fix can be accomplished by using the following commands:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

OR

- Use `sudo aws configure` to add AWS credentials to root. This fix requires you to continue using `sudo` for your SAM CLI commands.